# Residual charge on laptop

Tags: laptop, motherboard, charging

My Sony E series laptop is only 9 month old and seems to have a residual charge problem. My laptop was fully charged and was working fine a night before, but when I tried to switch it on the next morning it won't turn on. I called up Sony service center and they told me to take out the battery and power cord and hold the power button for 10 sec and then put the battery back and try to switch it on. I did that and it turned on. I tried to explore the reason for the problem and came to know that this is because of residual charge on the motherboard. I am having the same problem again and again, though not every time I switch it on. Can someone tell me a permanent solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you may have a faulty/dying battery (yes, 9 month old batteries can fail).

Call Sony back and tell them it's still happening frequently. Once in a while is normal, but if it's happening frequently then there's a problem.

If it's happening often enough, try leaving the battery out for a while (longer than it would normally take for the problem to show itself) and use it with only AC power.  If the problem doesn't happen with the battery out, then I'd definitely call Sony and look at getting the battery replaced (hopefully while it's still under warranty).

Comment: But my battery condition shows excellent and works without charging for 1-1.5 hrs can it still be a battery problem

Comment: If you're only getting 1-1.5 hours on a full charge I'd be concerned.  I'm not really familiar with Sony Vaio E series notebooks specifically, but based on what I can find (and what people usually demand in a notebook), even with the standard (4000mAh) battery you should be getting closer to 4 hours.

Comment: Also, what are you using to see your battery condition, and what do you use your laptop for?

Comment: I use my laptop mainly for watching movies and web browsing. And I am using Viao Control Center for viewing the battery condition

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: put your laptop in the freezer for 10-15 minutes. It will then boot up fine.

My theory is that a film of condensation will develop on the circuitry and allow residual charge to drain away.

Comment: How is this more of a permanent solution than what was described in the question?  Besides, it is not a good idea.

Comment: it works - would be bad idea if left too long - maybe fridge safer (this also works) - do you think the condensation theory could be correct?

Comment: Computers (electronics) and Water do not play well together. Condensation causes Corrosion. Corrosion is Bad.